# Remove write-block on USB flash drive

Tags: usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, read-only

I've read numerous guide and threads which discussed this matter, but I still can't use my USB drive.

No matter how and where I mount my USB drive (Kingston DTM30 64gb), it is write-protected (or read-only)

What I've tried so far:

- On Windows with `diskmgmt` format the disk. Failed as it's write-blocked.
- On Windows with `diskpart` select the disk and remove the write-block attribute. Failed since the USB flash drive is only recognized as a volume and the option is not given for a volume.
- On Windows (10 this time), with `diskpart` (`attributes disk clear readonly`), succeeded but drive is still read-only.
- On Windows with `chkdsk`, tried to fix issues but couldn't due to write-block.
- On Debian with `gparted` and `fdisk`, checked the flags and tried to format. Failed due to read-only mount. Also tried to re-mount as read/write with root, which also failed and mounted the drive again in read-only.
- On Debian with `hdparm` remove the read-only attribute. Succeeded, but was still read-only.
- On Debian with `dosfsck`, tried to fix issues with the filesystem, found issues but couldn't write changes/fixes.
- On live Ubunut, repeated the approaches from Debian, all of them failed again.

Is there any hope for my drive or can I just bin it?

It's barely 1 1/2 years old and hasn't been used too heavily.